# How to push lines from a text file to an array so they can be manipulated later

Tags: javascript, arrays, reader

I am trying to load a text file, read it line-by-line, and display it in a text area. Then I want to create a new array using each line from this text area so that I can manipulate the array in various ways later (e.g. to filter the content based on what each line contains).

So far I have gotten it to read the text file line by line and display it in the text area, but when I get to the commented section below, I'm struggling to figure out how to push each line onto a new array.

```
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let textArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
let files = input.files;

input.addEventListener("change", () => {
    let files = input.files;

    if (files.length == 0) return;

    const file = files[0];

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        const file = e.target.result;
        const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        const content = lines.join('\n');
        textArea.value = content; //trying to create a new array out of each line in this text area
        //could I use a For loop here on each line of the textArea? I am having trouble accessing it line by line
    reader.readAsText(file);

    //I have tried accessing the content variable from here but it says it is undefined.


    }   
);
```

I have had trouble trying to access the `content` variable outside of the function. Does this have to do with the scope?

Answer (score 0):

you must be use div instead of  textarea

but you add "contenteditable=true" attribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

also examine RegExp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp